# User consent prompt not showing all manifest scopes permissions when on first outlook add-in login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins, azure-authentication

I'm developing an Outlook add-on that requires Mail.ReadWrite permission.

I have added this permission in my registration app in Azure in my tenant **( Tenant A )**.

[image: azure grant]

I have also added them in the `manifest.xml` file

```
<Scopes>
  <Scope>Mail.ReadWrite</Scope>
  <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
  <Scope>User.Read</Scope>
  <Scope>profile</Scope>
  <Scope>openid</Scope>
</Scopes>
```

Here's how I call the login prompt (using Office.js library )

```
const token = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({
  allowConsentPrompt: true,
  allowSignInPrompt: true,
  forMSGraphAccess: true,
});
```

Then  I'm testing with a second tenant.

When the user in **tanant B** installs the add-in and run the app for the first time. A pop-up consent appears

[image: consent]

Here I don't see all the permissions that the app requests.

That causes an issue when I try to get graph API data. I get this error:

> 'AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the
> application with ID '1bc20309-c580-40ad-8133-c0c2bd127807' named
> 'summarizrApp'. Send an interactive authorization request for this
> user and resource.\r\nTrace ID:
> bb0919d6-3fbe-4a62-b5a3-7389b3da4100\r\nCorrelation ID:
> 76194227-9c13-4292-9088-aac8a7d037f1\r\nTimestamp: 2023-06-09
> 16:34:38Z'

When I log into `Entreprise applications` on test **tenant B** Azure portal I see that the app is added.

But I notice that not all permissions are there, only `profile`, `openid`, and `offline_access` but not `Mail.ReadWrite` or `User.Read`

[image]

Yet These permissions don't need an admin grant.

And Only when I click on Grant admin consent ( In enterprise application of **tenant B** Azure portal) then The missing permissions get added and the graph call works ok.

[image]

Then

[image]

After consent :

[image]

The missing permissions are here!

What I expect as behavior is that in the consent user window user gets all the permissions. Once he grants them, the Outlook add-on should be able to call the graph on behalf of the user.

[Authenticate a user with a single-sign-on token in an Outlook add-in](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/main/docs/outlook/authenticate-a-user-with-an-sso-token.md)

Comment: Hi, rukmini used `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345` to let users sign in and got popup window to let user consent. Could yo pls share your login request? Just want to check the scope inside your login request. And if the scope doesn't contain `mail.readwrite`, could you pls try to add it in the scope and test with the new login url?

Comment: I'm using `OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken` with params  `allowConsentPrompt` and `allowSignInPrompt` set to `true`, scopes are added in manifest.xml. for me it will check for permissions in manifest file.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, before reviewing the code, I just want to know the login url... Because your code is aim to generate the login url and let users sign in....

Comment: I'm not configuring any login url I'm using OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken with params allowConsentPrompt and allowSignInPrompt set to true. But I think `getAccessToken` don't prompt permissions. I should use msal

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your issue. When I see your prompt permissions window, I thought you had users to sign in first then users met this consent dialog.

Comment: @infodev While registering the addin, add scope as Admins and users. Refer to the documentation below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2#add-a-scope

Comment: Alreedy done this

Answer (score 0):

The admin for the tenant needs to provide the consent once, you can do that when installing the app. Otherwise the user will be required to to that on first login.

Comment: As I have explained it, the user is providing consent on the first login , but not ALL permissions are requested, here's the problem. Look on my screenshots I have added ones

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Multi-Tenant Application and added API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now, I tried to **authorize the users** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

The **`TenantB`** user got the **consent screen** including all the permissions like below:

[image]

Code got generated:

[image]

In the **`TenantB`** **Enterprise Application**, all the permissions are added in the user consent like below:

[image]

Now, I generated the **access token** using the below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access openid
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, all the scopes are present:

[image]

**I am able to call the Graph API successfully** by using the above generated access token like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
```

[image]

**To resolve the error**, try the below:

- Make sure to pass the **scope** as    **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`** to get consent of all the permissions.
- If still the issue persists, Grant Admin Consent and pass the scope as above.
- The user consent screen will appear after making the above changes.

Comment: I don't understand where should I add `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`? I'm using OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken(...). Should I absolutely pass by msal.js  or other library ?

Comment: Could you please include where are you passing the scope to generate the token.

Comment: The scope is in the Manifest.xml file. There is no other place where to pass it when using Office.js `getAccessToken` method. should I use msal library ?

Comment: Are you using this code to generate token? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75739772/unable-to-get-sso-token-in-outlook-add-in-app

Comment: I am referring to this line of code `const scopeName: string = process.env.SCOPE || "User.Read";`

Comment: Even by changing the scope to default that does not work . because the azure function is called when user has already logged-in/consent and want to get graph data. My issue is before this step. the issue is when sending consent prompt  the first time using `Office.auth.getAcessToken(...)` which is prompting only basic permissions and not all permissions in the manifest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254041/discussion-between-rukmini-and-infodev).

Comment: We were not able to repro this issue. Please confirn if this is resolved. @infodev

Comment: the issue is not resolved