# Msal loginPopup() method not working on macOS and windows outlook client

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, msal.js

I'm using msal library to login user in outlook add-in.

I'm calling `loginPopup` method in desktop macOS outlook client

```
let loginRequest = {
  scopes: ["profile","openid","user.read", "mail.readwrite"],
};
...

msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest)
```

I'm getting error :

> Error opening popup window. This can happen if you are using IE or if popups are blocked in the browser.

I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-known-issues-ie-edge-browsers#issues-due-to-popup-blockers) . I suppose so there is no solution.

I'm thinking so to use OfficeJS library to get token with SSO using

```
Office.auth.getAccessToken({
  allowConsentPrompt: true,
  allowSignInPrompt: true,
  forMSGraphAccess: true,
});
```

I want to know if there is a method to login silently in msal using the token generated by `Office.auth.getAccessToken()` method ?

For exemple inject the token in msal then use again msal to show consent popup.

ps: I'm using msal to be able to consent all scopes in manifest.xml. using only Office.js auth method don't prompt all permissions [for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76442303/user-consent-prompt-not-showing-all-manifest-scopes-permissions-when-on-first-ou)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Office Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui) for creating any popup message boxes. See [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) and [Authenticate and authorize with the Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api) for more information.

It's important to note that the Microsoft identity platform does not allow its sign in page to open in an iframe. When an Office Add-in is running in Office on the web, the task pane is an iframe. This means that you'll need to open the sign-in page by using a dialog box opened with the Office dialog API. This affects how you use authentication helper libraries.

Note, you can get authorization to Microsoft Graph data for your add-in by obtaining an access token to Microsoft Graph from the Microsoft identity platform. You can do this without relying on SSO through Office (or if SSO failed or is not supported). For more information, see [Access to Microsoft Graph without SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph-without-sso) which has more details and links to samples.

> using only Office.js auth method don't prompt all permissions

In that case you can post an issue to the https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues for implementing that or any other explanations.

Also you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.